# Controls of one Panel of a Splitcontainer hiding below other panel of the same contianer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox, richtextbox, splitcontainer

I have a winForms application which has a SplitContainer with two Panels and its Orientation is horizontal.The top/first Panel has a RichTextbox which spans the entire Panel.Inside this Richtextbox I have a Listbox which displays the values based on the input given in the RichTextbox. This Listbox will be Invisible and becomes Visible only when there are values to Display.

The Bottom/second Panel has only one Listbox which spans the entire Panel.

All the functionality of these controls are working fine.When the cursor reaches the end of the Richtextbox and Listbox is also displaying but the problem is this Listbox is hiding below Bottom panel.Is there any way to show this listbox of top panel over the bottom panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split Container panel have a property named AutoScroll. Set it to True and  Try.

This property automatically enables horizontal or vertical scroll bars according to controls inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,I tried this also but not working.
But I found the solution. Moved the Listbox which is inside the Rich textbox to outside the Split container to change the parent of the Control.Because of the Hierarchy of the Listbox its properties were overriding by Parent Control.Now Listbox is showing above the Panel 2 controls.